# How to add preference option to the liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, portal

I want to create a portlet where the portlet allow access to the remote application. That is the content of the portlet should be dynamic so for the same reason I want to add one option "Preferences" in the portlet (Where the look and feel and configuration options exists). In that preference page If will give some http url (http://localhost:8080/Myapp/Mypage) then on click of save button, the URL page should display in the portlet. How can I do that? Note I am going to use same portlet in different pages with different URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liferay's "Preferences" link shows the portlet in JSR-286 "edit" mode. That's all there is: If you implement this mode, you'll automatically get the Preferences link.

Why are they named differently? IMHO Edit-Mode is rather misleading as you're editing the preferences rather than any data displayed in the portlet.

Comment: Great I have deployed my portlet with view and edit mode. Now I am able to view the preference link. On click of the preference link it isredirecting to preference page (blank page). Now I want to add some input fields with save and cancel button to set the preferences. How can I do that? In which file do I need to add my preference input fields

Comment: To your first comment: Look up how to implement the JSR-286 Edit-Mode, e.g. in Liferay's Developer Guide. I don't understand your second comment, those are unrelated concepts IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You can use Liferay Iframe Portlet which allow access to the remote application.

Refer following url for detail description of look and feel and configuration options : [Iframe Portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe+Portlet#section-Iframe+Portlet-Embedding+remote+web+sites)

Comment: How can we create the Iframe portlet? Is there any development guidelines are there? Or Do I get the liferay Iframe portlet source code?

Comment: IFrame portlet comes bundled with liferay( OOTB). You just need to add that portlet and get going.

Comment: But I need to customize as my needs. Is there any way to get the source code?

Comment: you need to create Hook which override Iframe portlet's features.
You will find source code of Iframe Portlet in following path :  /LRTOMCAT/webapps/ROOT/html/portlet/iframe

Comment: I am able to see the frond end code, Where can I find the back end (Controller) code

Comment: From Here you can find back end code :- [IFrame Portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/iframe)

Comment: In your system you will find same back end code inside portal-impl.jar located at /LRTOMCAT/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib